# How to move or copy my git-cryp key to another laptop

Tags: git-crypt

I have my git-crypt key in another laptop and I would like to move this one to another one, I haven't seen any documentation related with this process or if it is possible  to achieve that, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think its not copy or paste, So i also try to solve Asap.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).